# Don't Display Menu Item If No Content Available

Tags: mysql, sql, vbscript, asp-classic

The website administrators are able to add new sub-menu links which in turn displays a page with the relevant records.

However, if there are no records to display, the page throws an error.

What I need is a way to check if there are available records, and if not, don't show the link.

The structure of tblMainMenu is:

```
MainMenuID
MainMenuName
MainMenuImage
DisplayRecord
PositionNumber
```

The structure of tblSubMenu is:

```
SubMenuID
SubMenuName
MainMenuID
DisplayRecord
PositionNumber
```

The structure of tblContent is:

```
ContentID
MainMenuID
SubMenuID
DisplayRecord
DisplayImage
UnDeleteRecord
UnDeleteImage
PositionNumber
ContentTitle
ContentData
ContentImage
ContentImageCaption
```

The page code, which also shows the SQL code is:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<!--#include virtual="/Connections/ENG.asp" -->
<%
Dim rsCharityDetails
Dim rsCharityDetails_cmd
Dim rsCharityDetails_numRows

Set rsCharityDetails_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsCharityDetails_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_ENG_STRING
rsCharityDetails_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblCharityDetails" 
rsCharityDetails_cmd.Prepared = true

Set rsCharityDetails = rsCharityDetails_cmd.Execute
rsCharityDetails_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim rsHeaderImage
Dim rsHeaderImage_cmd
Dim rsHeaderImage_numRows

Set rsHeaderImage_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsHeaderImage_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_ENG_STRING
rsHeaderImage_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MainMenuImage, MainMenuID FROM tblMainMenu WHERE MainMenuID = 3" 
rsHeaderImage_cmd.Prepared = true

Set rsHeaderImage = rsHeaderImage_cmd.Execute
rsHeaderImage_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim rsNavBar
Dim rsNavBar_cmd
Dim rsNavBar_numRows

Set rsNavBar_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsNavBar_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_ENG_STRING
rsNavBar_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblMainMenu WHERE DisplayRecord = 1 ORDER BY PositionNumber ASC" 
rsNavBar_cmd.Prepared = true

Set rsNavBar = rsNavBar_cmd.Execute
rsNavBar_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim rsWhoWeAre
Dim rsWhoWeAre_cmd
Dim rsWhoWeAre_numRows

Set rsWhoWeAre_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsWhoWeAre_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_ENG_STRING
rsWhoWeAre_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tblSubMenu.*, tblMainMenu.MainMenuName FROM tblSubMenu INNER JOIN tblMainMenu ON tblSubMenu.MainMenuID = tblMainMenu.MainMenuID WHERE tblSubMenu.DisplayRecord = 1 AND tblSubMenu.MainMenuID = 1 ORDER BY tblSubMenu.PositionNumber ASC" 
rsWhoWeAre_cmd.Prepared = true

Set rsWhoWeAre = rsWhoWeAre_cmd.Execute
rsWhoWeAre_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim rsWhatWeDo
Dim rsWhatWeDo_cmd
Dim rsWhatWeDo_numRows

Set rsWhatWeDo_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsWhatWeDo_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_ENG_STRING
rsWhatWeDo_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tblSubMenu.*, tblMainMenu.MainMenuName FROM tblSubMenu INNER JOIN tblMainMenu ON tblSubMenu.MainMenuID = tblMainMenu.MainMenuID WHERE tblSubMenu.DisplayRecord = 1 AND tblSubMenu.MainMenuID = 2 ORDER BY tblSubMenu.PositionNumber ASC" 
rsWhatWeDo_cmd.Prepared = true

Set rsWhatWeDo = rsWhatWeDo_cmd.Execute
rsWhatWeDo_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim rsOurProjects
Dim rsOurProjects_cmd
Dim rsOurProjects_numRows

Set rsOurProjects_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsOurProjects_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_ENG_STRING
rsOurProjects_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tblSubMenu.*, tblMainMenu.MainMenuName FROM tblSubMenu INNER JOIN tblMainMenu ON tblSubMenu.MainMenuID = tblMainMenu.MainMenuID WHERE tblSubMenu.DisplayRecord = 1 AND tblSubMenu.MainMenuID = 3 ORDER BY tblSubMenu.PositionNumber ASC" 
rsOurProjects_cmd.Prepared = true

Set rsOurProjects = rsOurProjects_cmd.Execute
rsOurProjects_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim rsSupportUs
Dim rsSupportUs_cmd
Dim rsSupportUs_numRows

Set rsSupportUs_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsSupportUs_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_ENG_STRING
rsSupportUs_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tblSubMenu.*, tblMainMenu.MainMenuName FROM tblSubMenu INNER JOIN tblMainMenu ON tblSubMenu.MainMenuID = tblMainMenu.MainMenuID WHERE tblSubMenu.DisplayRecord = 1 AND tblSubMenu.MainMenuID = 4 ORDER BY tblSubMenu.PositionNumber ASC" 
rsSupportUs_cmd.Prepared = true

Set rsSupportUs = rsSupportUs_cmd.Execute
rsSupportUs_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim rsLearnMore
Dim rsLearnMore_cmd
Dim rsLearnMore_numRows

Set rsLearnMore_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsLearnMore_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_ENG_STRING
rsLearnMore_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tblSubMenu.*, tblMainMenu.MainMenuName FROM tblSubMenu INNER JOIN tblMainMenu ON tblSubMenu.MainMenuID = tblMainMenu.MainMenuID WHERE tblSubMenu.DisplayRecord = 1 AND tblSubMenu.MainMenuID = 5 ORDER BY tblSubMenu.PositionNumber ASC" 
rsLearnMore_cmd.Prepared = true

Set rsLearnMore = rsLearnMore_cmd.Execute
rsLearnMore_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim rsContent__idSMenu
rsContent__idSMenu = "7"
If (Request.QueryString("idSMenu")    <> "") Then 
  rsContent__idSMenu = Request.QueryString("idSMenu")   
End If
%>
<%
Dim rsContent
Dim rsContent_cmd
Dim rsContent_numRows

Set rsContent_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsContent_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_ENG_STRING
rsContent_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tblContent.*, tblSubMenu.SubMenuName, tblMainMenu.MainMenuName FROM (tblContent LEFT JOIN tblSubMenu ON tblContent.SubMenuID = tblSubMenu.SubMenuID) INNER JOIN tblMainMenu ON tblContent.MainMenuID = tblMainMenu.MainMenuID WHERE tblContent.DisplayRecord = 1 AND tblContent.SubMenuID = ? ORDER BY tblContent.PositionNumber ASC" 
rsContent_cmd.Prepared = true
rsContent_cmd.Parameters.Append rsContent_cmd.CreateParameter("param1", 5, 1, -1, rsContent__idSMenu) ' adDouble

Set rsContent = rsContent_cmd.Execute
rsContent_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim navBar__numRows
Dim navBar__index

navBar__numRows = -1
navBar__index = 0
rsNavBar_numRows = rsNavBar_numRows + navBar__numRows
%>
<%
Dim WhoWeAre__numRows
Dim WhoWeAre__index

WhoWeAre__numRows = -1
WhoWeAre__index = 0
rsWhoWeAre_numRows = rsWhoWeAre_numRows + WhoWeAre__numRows
%>
<%
Dim WhatWeDo__numRows
Dim WhatWeDo__index

WhatWeDo__numRows = -1
WhatWeDo__index = 0
rsWhatWeDo_numRows = rsWhatWeDo_numRows + WhatWeDo__numRows
%>
<%
Dim OurProjects__numRows
Dim OurProjects__index

OurProjects__numRows = -1
OurProjects__index = 0
rsOurProjects_numRows = rsOurProjects_numRows + OurProjects__numRows
%>
<%
Dim SupportUs__numRows
Dim SupportUs__index

SupportUs__numRows = -1
SupportUs__index = 0
rsSupportUs_numRows = rsSupportUs_numRows + SupportUs__numRows
%>
<%
Dim LearnMore__numRows
Dim LearnMore__index

LearnMore__numRows = -1
LearnMore__index = 0
rsLearnMore_numRows = rsLearnMore_numRows + LearnMore__numRows
%>
<%
Dim Article__numRows
Dim Article__index

Article__numRows = -1
Article__index = 0
rsContent_numRows = rsContent_numRows + Article__numRows
%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
<!-- disable iPhone inital scale -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

<title><%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value)%> || <%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%> || <%=(rsCharityDetails.Fields.Item("CharityName").Value)%></title>

<script src="../scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery NailThumb Plugin - any image to any thumbnail Examples and documentation at: http://www.garralab.com/nailthumb.php -->
<script src="../scripts/jquery.nailthumb.1.1.js"></script>
<!-- Lightbox2 v2.51 by Lokesh Dhakar For more information, visit: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ -->
<script src="../scripts/lightbox.js"></script>

<!-- Lightbox css -->
<link href="../scripts/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!-- main css -->
<link href="../scripts/mfm-standard-stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- Non desktop css -->
<link href="../scripts/mfm-media-queries.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- html5.js for IE less than 9 -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- css3-mediaqueries.js for IE less than 9 -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<%
thisPageID = (rsContent.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value)
thisPageID = replace(thisPageID, " ", "-")
thisPageID = LCase(thisPageID)
'Response.Write(thisPageID)
%>

<body id="<% Response.Write(thisPageID) %>">

<div id="wrapper" class="innerWidth">
<header>
<!--#include file="includes/header.asp" -->
</header>

<nav>
<!--#include file="includes/navbar.asp" -->
</nav>

<!-- Page Content -->
<% IF rsContent.Fields.Item("SubMenuName") <> rsContent.Fields.Item("ContentTitle") THEN %>
<h1 id="pageTitle"><%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></h1>
<% END IF %>

<!-- Article -->
<% 
While ((Article__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rsContent.EOF)) 
%>
<article id="content" class="innerWidth">
    <% IF (IsNull(rsContent.Fields.Item("ContentImage").Value)) OR (rsContent.Fields.Item("DisplayImage").Value) = "0" THEN %>
    <div class="withoutImage">
    <h1><%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("ContentTitle").Value)%></h1> <!-- Content Title -->
    <%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("ContentData").Value)%>
    </div> <!-- Page Content -->
    <% ELSE %>
    <!-- Image -->
    <div class="withImage">
    <h1><%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("ContentTitle").Value)%></h1> <!-- Content Title -->
    <img src="../images/system-images/polaroid-frame.gif" id="frame">
    <div class="nailthumb-container" id="frameImage"> <!-- Thumbnail Container -->
    <a href="<%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("ContentImage").Value)%>" rel="lightbox" title="<%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("ContentImageCaption").Value)%>"><img src="<%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("ContentImage").Value)%>"></a> <!-- Image -->
    </div>
    <span id="frameImageCaption"><%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("ContentImageCaption").Value)%></span>
    <%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("ContentData").Value)%>
    </div>
    <% END IF %>
</article>

<% 
Article__index=Article__index+1
Article__numRows=Article__numRows-1
rsContent.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
<!-- /Article -->

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.nailthumb-container').nailthumb({fitDirection:'top center'});
});
</script>

<!-- /Page Content -->

<div class="push"></div>

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->

<footer>
  <!--#include file="includes/footer.asp" -->
</footer>

</body>
</html>
<%
rsCharityDetails.Close()
Set rsCharityDetails = Nothing
%>
<%
rsHeaderImage.Close()
Set rsHeaderImage = Nothing
%>
<%
rsNavBar.Close()
Set rsNavBar = Nothing
%>
<%
rsWhoWeAre.Close()
Set rsWhoWeAre = Nothing
%>
<%
rsWhatWeDo.Close()
Set rsWhatWeDo = Nothing
%>
<%
rsOurProjects.Close()
Set rsOurProjects = Nothing
%>
<%
rsSupportUs.Close()
Set rsSupportUs = Nothing
%>
<%
rsLearnMore.Close()
Set rsLearnMore = Nothing
%>
<%
rsContent.Close()
Set rsContent = Nothing
%>
```

The menu code, which is an included file, `navbar.asp`, is:

```
<%
pageName = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") '& "<br>"
loc = instrRev(pageName,"/")
pageName = mid(pageName, loc+1, len(pageName) - loc)
%>

<script type="text/javascript">
//jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery("h3 a").click(function (e) {

jQuery(".subMenuRow").hide();
mID=this.id
mID=mID.replace("Main_Menu_", "");
jQuery("#"+mID).show().delay(6500).fadeOut(); 

return(false);
})
})
</script> 

<ul>
<%
While ((navBar__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rsNavBar.EOF)) 
%>
<%
thisPageClass = (rsNavBar.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value)
thisPageClass = replace(thisPageClass, " ", "-")
thisPageClass = LCase(thisPageClass)
%>
<% If (rsNavBar.Fields.Item("MainMenuID").Value) = "6" Then %>
    <li><a href="default.asp" class="home"><h3><%=(rsNavBar.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value)%></h3></a></li>
<% ElseIf (rsNavBar.Fields.Item("MainMenuID").Value) = "7" Then %>
    <li><a href="contact-us.asp" class="<% Response.Write(thisPageClass) %>"><h3><%=(rsNavBar.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value)%></h3></a></li>
<% Else %>
    <li><h3><a id="Main_Menu_<%=(rsNavBar.Fields.Item("MainMenuID").Value)%>" href="<% Response.Write(pageName) %>?show=<%=(rsNavBar.Fields.Item("MainMenuID").Value)%>" class="<% Response.Write(thisPageClass) %>"><%=(rsNavBar.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value)%></a></h3></li>
<% End If %>
<% 
navBar__index=navBar__index+1
navBar__numRows=navBar__numRows-1
rsNavBar.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
</ul>

<%
'declare 1 for each layer
Dim vis1, vis2, vis3, vis4, vis5

Select Case request("show")
  Case 1 ' Who We Are
    vis1 = "block"
    vis2 = "none"
    vis3 = "none"
    vis4 = "none"
    vis5 = "none"
  Case 2 ' What We Do
    vis1 = "none"
    vis2 = "block"
    vis3 = "none"
    vis4 = "none"
    vis5 = "none"
  Case 3 ' Our Projects
    vis1 = "none"
    vis2 = "none"
    vis3 = "block"
    vis4 = "none"
    vis5 = "none"
  Case 4 ' Support Us
    vis1 = "none"
    vis2 = "none"
    vis3 = "none"
    vis4 = "block"
    vis5 = "none"
  Case 5 ' Learn More
    vis1 = "none"
    vis2 = "none"
    vis3 = "none"
    vis4 = "none"
    vis5 = "block"
  Case else
    vis1 = "none"
    vis2 = "none"
    vis3 = "none"
    vis4 = "none"
    vis5 = "none"
End Select
%>

<!-- WHO WE ARE -->
<div id="1" style="display:<%=vis1%>;" class="subMenuRow">
<ul class="innerWidth">
<% 
While ((WhoWeAre__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rsWhoWeAre.EOF)) 
%>
<%
strPageName = Replace (rsWhoWeAre.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value," ","-")
strPageName = Lcase(strPageName)
%>
<% If (rsWhoWeAre.Fields.Item("SubMenuID").Value) = "3" Then %>
<li><a href="our-development-partners.asp"><h3><%=(rsWhoWeAre.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></h3></a></li>
<% Else %>
<li><a href="<% Response.Write(strPageName) %>.asp?idSMenu=<%=(rsWhoWeAre.Fields.Item("SubMenuID").Value)%>"><h3><%=(rsWhoWeAre.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></h3></a></li>
<% End If %>
<% 
WhoWeAre__index=WhoWeAre__index+1
WhoWeAre__numRows=WhoWeAre__numRows-1
rsWhoWeAre.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- /WHO WE ARE -->

<!-- WHAT WE DO -->
<div id="2" style="display:<%=vis2%>;" class="subMenuRow">
<ul class="innerWidth">
<% 
While ((WhatWeDo__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rsWhatWeDo.EOF)) 
%>
<%
strPageName = Replace (rsWhatWeDo.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value," ","-")
strPageName = Lcase(strPageName)
%>
<% If (rsWhatWeDo.Fields.Item("SubMenuID").Value) = "6" Then %>
<li><a href="map.asp?idSMenu=<%=(rsWhatWeDo.Fields.Item("SubMenuID").Value)%>"><h3><%=(rsWhatWeDo.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></h3></a></li>
<% Else %>
<li><a href="<% Response.Write(strPageName) %>.asp?idSMenu=<%=(rsWhatWeDo.Fields.Item("SubMenuID").Value)%>"><h3><%=(rsWhatWeDo.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></h3></a></li>
<% End If %>
<% 
WhatWeDo__index=WhatWeDo__index+1
WhatWeDo__numRows=WhatWeDo__numRows-1
rsWhatWeDo.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- /WHAT WE DO -->

<!-- OUR PROJECTS -->
<div id="3" style="display:<%=vis3%>;" class="subMenuRow">
<ul class="innerWidth">
<% 
While ((OurProjects__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rsOurProjects.EOF)) 
%>
<%
strPageName = Replace (rsOurProjects.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value," ","-")
strPageName = Lcase(strPageName)
%>
<li><a href="<% Response.Write(strPageName) %>.asp?idSMenu=<%=(rsOurProjects.Fields.Item("SubMenuID").Value)%>"><h3><%=(rsOurProjects.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></h3></a></li>
<% 
OurProjects__index=OurProjects__index+1
OurProjects__numRows=OurProjects__numRows-1
rsOurProjects.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- /OUR PROJECTS -->

<!-- SUPPORT US -->
<div id="4" style="display:<%=vis4%>;" class="subMenuRow">
<ul class="innerWidth">
<% 
While ((SupportUs__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rsSupportUs.EOF)) 
%>
<%
strPageName = Replace (rsSupportUs.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value," ","-")
strPageName = Lcase(strPageName)
%>
<% IF (rsSupportUs.Fields.Item("SubMenuID").Value = "16") THEN %>
<li><a href="http://moneyformadagascar.blogspot.co.uk/p/appeals.html" target="new"><h3><%=(rsSupportUs.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></h3></a></li>
<% ELSE %>
<li><a href="<% Response.Write(strPageName) %>.asp"><h3><%=(rsSupportUs.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></h3></a></li>
<% END IF %>
<% 
SupportUs__index=SupportUs__index+1
SupportUs__numRows=SupportUs__numRows-1
rsSupportUs.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- /SUPPORT US -->

<!-- LEARN MORE -->
<div id="5" style="display:<%=vis5%>;" class="subMenuRow">
<ul class="innerWidth">
<% 
While ((LearnMore__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rsLearnMore.EOF)) 
%>
<%
strPageName = Replace (rsLearnMore.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value," ","-")
strPageName = Lcase(strPageName)
%>
<% IF (rsLearnMore.Fields.Item("SubMenuID").Value = "17") THEN %>
<li><a href="http://moneyformadagascar.blogspot.co.uk" target="new"><h3><%=(rsLearnMore.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></h3></a></li>
<% ELSE %>
<li><a href="<% Response.Write(strPageName) %>.asp"><h3><%=(rsLearnMore.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></h3></a></li>
<% END IF %>
<% 
LearnMore__index=LearnMore__index+1
LearnMore__numRows=LearnMore__numRows-1
rsLearnMore.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- /LEARN MORE -->
```

I think I need to find a way to check if the relevant SubMenuID appears in the content table but I can't quite figure out how.

Many thanks in advance for the help and advice.

Regards

Pb

Comment: which line throws the error?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit about the error. Basically, it's a blank page. The actual error concerns BOF or EOF or no current record. The line in question is:`<title><%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value)%> || <%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%> || <%=(rsCharityDetails.Fields.Item("CharityName").Value)%></title>`. The error is expected because there is no record. This is why I need to check if there is a record to display.

Comment: I would suggest to add variables and use verification like "if Not RS.EOF then variable=something" from recordset. This way you will only have strings there and nulls or empty variables will be omitted. At worse you can use response.write if recordset have value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured. I added `ContentID` as a `LEFT JOIN` and adding a `GROUP BY` statement in the SQL to make sure the `SubMenuID` only shows once. Then use `NOT IFNULL` in an `IF... THEN... ELSE` statement. For Example,
SQL Code:

```
SELECT tblSubMenu.*, tblMainMenu.MainMenuName, tblContent.ContentID
FROM (tblSubMenu INNER JOIN tblMainMenu ON tblSubMenu.MainMenuID = tblMainMenu.MainMenuID) INNER JOIN tblContent ON tblSubMenu.SubMenuID = tblContent.SubMenuID
WHERE tblSubMenu.DisplayRecord = 1 AND tblSubMenu.MainMenuID = 3 GROUP BY tblSubMenu.SubMenuID
ORDER BY tblSubMenu.PositionNumber ASC
```

Code in navbar.asp:

```
<!-- OUR PROJECTS -->
<div id="3" style="display:<%=vis3%>;" class="subMenuRow">
<ul class="innerWidth">
<% 
While ((OurProjects__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rsOurProjects.EOF)) 
%>
<%
strPageName = Replace (rsOurProjects.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value," ","-")
strPageName = Lcase(strPageName)
%>
<% If NOT ISNULL (rsOurProjects.Fields.Item("ContentID").Value) Then %>
<li><a href="<% Response.Write(strPageName) %>.asp?idSMenu=<%=(rsOurProjects.Fields.Item("SubMenuID").Value)%>"><h3><%=(rsOurProjects.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></h3></a></li>
<% End If %>
<% 
OurProjects__index=OurProjects__index+1
OurProjects__numRows=OurProjects__numRows-1
rsOurProjects.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- /OUR PROJECTS -->
```

Regards

Pb

Answer (score 1):

Top question from the script you posted is: where did you get value for your Article__numRows variable?

I do see that in loop you doing Article_*numRows=Article*_numRows-1 but before you start decrementing something with current value bigger then -1 you should have set this value somewhere like

Article__numRows=rsContent_numRows

but according to your script all row counter variables set either to 0 or -1 which will make any loops go wanky and not stoping when you reach BOF or end of record-sets(EOF).

Comment: Further down the page is the repeat-region that the Article_numRows variable works on. It shows all the records related to the idSMenu variable which is set by the SubMenuID in the navbar.asp file.

Comment: Sorry Marty but I do not see this at all. And ASP does not work this way: unless you have value of the variable before you start processing -- it will not be used.

Comment: I don't really know what I'm doing and I'm not quite sure what you mean, but at the risk of teaching my grandmother to suck eggs, the link has the variable idSMenu attached to it that is the SubMenuID that controls which records to display on the page, ie: our-projects.asp?idSMenu=12. The problem occurs (correctly) when there is no record to display. I'm not worried about there not being a record to display, just how to hide the link in the menu system until there is a record to display (if that makes sense).

Comment: here is one way to do this within the loop of yours: 
      <%If not rsContent.EOF then  %>
    <%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value)%>  ||
    <%end if %>
   
    <%If not rsContent.EOF then  %>
     <%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%>  ||
     <%end if %>
    
     <%If not rsCharityDetails.EOF then  %>
      <%=(rsCharityDetails.Fields.Item("CharityName").Value)%>
     <% end if %> 
      </title>

Comment: Hi All Blond. Thanks for the reply, however, it doesn't answer my question. My question doesn't concern the page coming up blank. I know what the cause is for this. I'm looking for a way to hide a link in the menu if there is no corresponding SubMenuID in rsContent. I've tried `<% If (rsContent.Fields.Item("SubMenuID").Value) = rsOurProjects.Fields.Item("SubMenuID").Value) Then %>...` and slight variations but to no avail.

Comment: That is exactly what this does:  <%If not rsContent.EOF then %> <%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value)%> || <%end if %> If it is EOF then nothing there. You can do same verification for main menu with obvious change to which EOF you need there. Also you can check if actual value are empty or not within same IF statement and act accordingly. Check lenght of the string like cStr(rsContent.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value).Trim.length and if it is more then 0 then you have a value and not an empty string.

Comment: When I tried this on the page, the error moved to line 221 (`thisPageID = (rsContent.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value)`). It will continue to do this each time it comes across rsContent. I've tried using part of this code in the menu system but the link still remains.

Comment: man you need to see if your rsContent have anything before you use it, otherwise it will always kick you in a butt. Make sure that it is not empty and it is not EOF and only after that use it.

Comment: I've used an EOF check on other pages since and for that it works perfectly but in this case I needed to check if a particular menu item had some content attached to it. The way it works at the moment is if the menu has some content, display the menu item, if not, don't. I don't know much about this but it works so I'm leaving it alone. I'm sure, in the future, doing more things along these lines, I'll get better, well, here's hoping anyway.

Comment: It does not matter. You must see if your recordset have anything or not before you try to use it.

Comment: The recordset isn't empty. It only returned an empty recordset if the link with no corresponding record in the content table was clicked. I figured out I needed to check if there was a record in the content table for the menu item.